# The $9$th tetration of $-\sqrt2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, recreational-mathematics

Let $^na$ denote the $n$th tetration of $a$, so that $^0a=1$ and
$$^{n+1}a=a^{^na}$$
for $n=0,1,\dots$. (For complex $x$ and $y$, here we use the definition $x^y:=e^{y\ln x}$, where $\ln$ is the principal branch of the logarithm.)

It appears that $^9(-\sqrt2)$ is very close to $1$, but not exactly $1$ — so that the sequence $\big(^n(-\sqrt2)\big)$ is almost(?) periodic:
$$^9(-\sqrt2)-1\approx(4.99+1.51\, i)\times10^{-45}.$$

Is this a mere coincidence or is there an explanation for this?

Comment: It seems like the $^{n}(-\sqrt{2})$ is small in absolute value until $n=6$, then for $n=7$ it gets out of hand ($^{7}(-\sqrt{2})\sim-33+29i$), so that $^{8}(-\sqrt{2})$ is almost $0$ and $^{9}(-\sqrt{2})$ is almost $1$. In general if at some point $a_n=^{n}(-\sqrt{2})$ satisfies that $a_n\cdot\ln(-\sqrt{2})$ has a very negative real part, the same thing is going to happen, so at least it is not such a big coincidence

Comment: @SamHopkins : Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @SaúlRM : Thank you for your comment. I think this is the explanation. If you care to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Okay, I will do that

Comment: As soon as this sequence gets its real part sufficiently big and negative, the next one will be very close to zero, and, consequently, second next will be almost equal to 1. Tetration of a (more or less random) complex number looks pretty much like a random process to me (...until it's not random, as I pointed out), so I'd totally expect it to fall somewhat deep into negative half-plane at some point. Also I'm doubtful about "periodicity"; even things as tiny as $10^{-45}$ will quickly blow up under iterated exponents

Comment: @DenisT about the "periodicity" of the sequence, it seems like if we let $f(x)=e^{x\ln(-\sqrt{2})}$, then $f^9$ should have a very small derivative near $x=1$ (small like $<10^{-30}$ in norm). I wouldn't be surprised if the sequence $a_n=^{9n}(-\sqrt{2})$ converges to something close to $1$

Comment: @DenisT : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms : Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't understand it.  In particular, it is not clear to me what you mean by "reversed the operation to that of $\log()$". In your expression (definition?) for $\log_b(z,2)$ there seems to be no $b$. The meaning of your table is also unclear to me.

Comment: Upps, in $\log_b(z,k=0)$ the $b$ means the base $b=-\sqrt 2$ (which had no letter assigned to in your question). The meaning of my table: if you start at $a_9$ trying to get backwards to $a_0$ applying $\log_b()$ to base $b=-\sqrt 2$ you cannot use the principal branch of the $\log()$ to arrive at your $a_8$. Sorry, seems I've been much sloppy today. Perhaps this is also only too tangent to your problem...

Comment: About repunits and frozen digits in tetration with a high hyperexponent, let me share a couple of papers that I've recently written, proving that integer tetration is the only hyperoperator which is characterized by a constant "congruence speed" for any base that is not a multiple of $10$: https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.02622 [1] and also https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07956 [2].
In [1], it has been shown that the congruence speed of any given base depends only on the $15$ solutions of the equation $y^5=y$ in the commutative ring of $10$-adic integers.

Comment: Thus, tetration has a very stable tail of frozen digits and repunits occur quite often, at the end (e.g., see [1], Equations (6)&(7), second line).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not a huge coincidence: the idea is that the sequence $a_n={}^{n}(-\sqrt{2})$ has small norm until $n=6$, then it gets out of hand for $n=7$ ($a_7\sim-33+29i$), so that $a_8=e^{a_7\ln(-\sqrt{2})}$ is almost $0$ and $a_9$ is almost $1$.

In general when sequences of this type get out of hand (increase exponentially in norm), it seems likely that at some point you will raise $e$ to a number with a big negative real part so a similar phenomenon will happen.

In fact, as you say the sequence is almost periodic, in the sense that $a_{9n}$ converges to some point close to $1$ when $n$ goes to infinity. Let $k=\ln(-\sqrt{2}):=\pi i+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ and let $f(x)=e^{kx}$, so that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. Then $f'(x)=kf(x)$, and by the chain rule we get that $(f^n)'(x)=k^n\prod_{i=1}^nf^i(x)$.

Now let $g(x)=f^9(x)$. We know that $|g(1)-1|<10^{-40}$, so by the proof of the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), to check that $g^n(1)$ converges to some point close to $1$ it is enough with the following proposition:

**Proposition:** If $x\in B(1,10^{-30})$, then $|g'(x)|<\frac{1}{2}$.

To prove it, note that $|g'(x)|=|k|^9\lvert\prod_{i=1}^9f^i(x)\rvert\leq10^6\prod_{i=1}^9|f^i(x)|$, so we just have to estimate $|f^i(x)|$. It is also easy to check that $|f^i(x)|<1.49$ for $i=1,\dots,6$. Also, for any $x$ with $|x|<1.5$ we have $|f'(x)|=|kf(x)|\leq4|f(x)|\leq4e^{3.5\cdot1.5}<1000$.

This implies by induction that $|f^i(x)-f^i(1)|\leq1000|f^{i-1}(x)-f^{i-1}(1)|$ for $i\leq6$, so $|f^6(x)-f^6(1)|\leq10^{-15}$, so $|f^7(x)-f^7(1)|<10^{-10}$ and $|f^8(x)|=|e^{kf^7(x)}|\sim |e^{-103-95i}|<|10^{-40}|$. So, finally, $|g'(x)|\leq10^6\prod_{i=1}^9|f^i(x)|\leq10^6\cdot1.49^7\cdot100\cdot10^{-40}\leq\frac{1}{2}$, as we wanted.

Comment: A nice addition about the convergence!

Comment: It is not the first time that I've seen these kind of questions involving tetration, but this is a final answer which could be copy-pasted and holds for almost all of them. Very clear explanation!